# how to overcome pinentry of gpg using python when we run an gpg command in python script

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I tried the following code which is working perfect, but it's not taking my passphrase. when I run this code I get a popup which asks to enter the passphrase for every time I run the python code in new cmd. But I want to automate this. So please suggest a better option to take passphrase for python script itself.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

output_file_name = 'abc.zip'
input_file_name = 'abc.zip.pgp'

args = ['gpg', '-o', output_file_name, '--decrypt', input_file_name]

proc = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,shell=True)

proc.stdin.write('passphrase\n')
proc.stdin.flush()

stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```